# Compare two objects in an array using jquery and insert the missing element

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am having multiple objects in an array i want to make the element in each object same

```
var objectArray = [obj1,obj2,obj3.........]

obj1 ={
2002-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1854095,
2003-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1531632,
2005-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1887739,
2006-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1754043,
2007-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2038664,
2008-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2270297,
2009-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.211827,
2011-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2396887,
2012-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2618066,
2013-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2677819,
var_descripcion: "Asalariados con contrato a término fijo (en %)"}

obj2 ={
2002-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1854095,
2003-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1531632,
2005-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1887739,
2006-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.1754043,
2007-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2038664,
2011-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2396887,
2012-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2618066,
2013-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2677819,
var_descripcion: "Asalariados con contrato a término fijo (en %)"}
```

I want to compare this arrays and insert the missing value in second arrays ie,

```
2008-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.2270297 & 2009-Edad 15 a 64 años: 0.211827
```

but value as 0

In this way I want to make all the objects in array similar

Please help;

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do that. You will find that after having executed normalizeArray on the test array that the second object in the array will have the "second" property initialized to 0. [Here's a fiddle of it working.](http://codepen.io/ozrevulsion/pen/gaZvYP)

```
function mergeObject(from, to) {
  for(var prop in from) {
    if (typeof(to[prop]) === 'undefined') {
      to[prop] = 0;
    }
  }

  return to;
}

function normalizeArray(arr) {
  var schema = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    schema = mergeObject(arr[i], schema);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = mergeObject(schema, arr[i]);
  }
}

var test1 = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
}

var test2 = {
  first: 1,
  third: 3
}

var testArray = [test1, test2];

normalizeArray(testArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare the arrays;

```
            var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5],
                array2 = [5,4,3,2,1],
                array3 = [1,2,,6,7,8];

            function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
                return $(arr1).not(arr2).length == 0 && $(arr2).not(arr1).length == 0
            };
```